# I want OnComplete event to be fired at the end of playlist only

Tags: javascript, jwplayer6

Notice the event:

```
 onComplete: function() {
```

in

```
events: {
     onComplete: function() {
     var x= document.getElementById("aID");
     x.style.visibility = "hidden";
   }       
};
```

This event is run after each video completion. I want this event to be fired ONLY ONCE at the end of the playlist, and not after each video in the playlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for the event [**`onPlaylistComplete`**](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference#playlist):

> Fired when the player is done playing all items in the playlist. However, if the repeat option is set true, this is never fired.